# Adding custom Oauth2 provider in Firebase

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, custom-authentication

We are creating an app and using firebase authentication. We have an existing oauth2 provider in our organization. Is it possible to add this custom provider in firebase? So we will add a new client in our identity provider and configure firebase so that it can accept token from it.

Comment: Have you found something? I'm in a similar situation, meanwhile the most promising string was [firebase admin auth API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin)

Comment: @OhadCohen I haven't

Comment: +Anup ty for the answer